# How can I get libdbcapi_r.so, libdbcapi_r.dylib needed for sqlany-django?

Tags: django, sybase, sqlanywhere, sqlanydb

I installed and configured `sqlany-django`, but have error `Could not load dbcapi: Tried: dbcapi.dll, libdbcapi_r.so, libdbcapi_r.dylib`.

I installed `sqlany-django` with `pip install sqlany-django`. According to [this](https://github.com/sqlanywhere/sqlany-django) I should run
`$ . /opt/sqlanywhere16/bin64/sa_config.sh` , but I don't have a script `sa_config.sh`.

I tried to download `libdbcapi_r.so` or `libdbcapi_r.dylib` but I can't find it even [here](https://github.com/sqlanywhere/sqlanydb/issues/2). Then I'd like to add the path to library to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

How can I solve this?

my system is `Ubuntu 18.04`

```
Django==1.8
sqlany-django==1.13
sqlanydb==1.0.11
```

Comment: I create this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70675071/how-get-a-component-or-software-that-adds-libdbcapi-r-so-sap-family-sybase, im in the same problem, but about my reaseach I find you  must to install something like sqla1201_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz  I use this page  https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/SAP+SQL+Anywhere+Database+Client+Download, but all package seems corrupt, but Im sure if you find a correct package of database cliente you can solve the problem

Comment: Thank you. Finally, I have found the solution [here](https://kcsharepoint.home.blog/2021/08/02/python-connect-to-sybase-sap-database-linux-based-os-only/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70675071/how-get-a-component-or-software-that-adds-libdbcapi-r-so-sap-family-sybase,

Im in the same problem, but about my reaseach I find you must to install something like sqla1201_client_linux_x86x64.tar.gz(is the package for linux)
I use this page https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/SAP+SQL+Anywhere+Database+Client+Download,

but all package seems corrupt, but Im sure if you find a correct package of database cliente you can solve the problem

also this link has the complete detail aboutthe proces of instalation
link https://kcsharepoint.home.blog/2021/08/02/python-connect-to-sybase-sap-database-linux-based-os-only/

Comment: I'm adding this url, which may be helpful https://kcsharepoint.home.blog/2021/08/02/python-connect-to-sybase-sap-database-linux-based-os-only/